# CSS override issue for a parent child page

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, overriding

I have a parent page which uses Bootstrap 2 , now i am including a child page which happens to be newUI which uses Bootstrap 3.  My child page still uses bootstrap2. either the parent page UI breaks or the child page uI breaks. Pretty messy, How do i fix this?

It not just a single CSS class. I am looking to override the entire css file.

Something like.

1. Parent Page should use Bootstrap 2.
2. Child page Should use Bootstrap 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend name-spacing both pages, it would be very trivial if you had less or sass to create ancestor descendent relationship like:

```
.parent-page-wrap {

     .button {
         color: #BADA55
     }
}

.child-page-wrap {
     .button {
         color:#BAD6E5
     }

}
```

You can do it the old fashioned way:

```
.parent-page-wrap .button {color: #BADA55}
.child-page-wrap .button {color: #BAD6E5
```

Comment: ya its a clean approach, but right now its a huge rework for me as both my parent and child pages are pretty complex. Looking for something to handle the overriding.

Answer (score 0):

You need to migrate from bootstrap 2 to 3, that's the best option.

Try these link:

http://www.bootply.com/bootstrap-3-migration-guide

http://code.divshot.com/bootstrap3_upgrader/

Or else use different external stylesheet links for the Parent and child pages.

Hope this helps.......

Comment: The issue is i still want to use both frameworks in same page.

Comment: @SwatiG Thats not a good idea. Both the files have some similar styles. it will definitely override each other. You can't have both in same page.